# The male name Yona

Tags: names

It is most common for the name Yona to be used for males. There are many female Yona's too. In Parshas Noach the Pasuk says V'Hayona Lo Motzo Monoach which is a Loshon Nekeiva (female dialect). How did the name Yona become a male name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the name of Yona Hanavi, and he was a male.

Comment: so how did he get his name?

Comment: @Gershon: now you're asking for something that's beyond the scope of linguistics.

Comment: Maybe you can call Yona to both male and female bird and Noah just "occasionally" took a female bird. However the male version was caught more because of Yona Hanavi.

Comment: The coincidence of grammatical gender and gender of the signified person when it comes to naming after pre-existing animals or objects isn't necessarily meaningful. Male ostriches, for example, are also _b'nos ya'ana_, and it would therefore not be problematic (for grammatical reasons, irrespective of aesthetics) to name a baby boy _Bas Ya'ana_.

Comment: Please note: My prior comment makes a lot of debatable assumptions. Another example is the name _Simcha_, which is grammatically feminine.